# SELECTing Products from products table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I want to select the rows from `products` table.
The products are `season` based.

each product `row/entity` contains a column named `id_season`

and `seasons` table looks like

```
id | season_name | active | created | modified
```

Season names are Year like 2016,2017,2018 ...

I want to select all the products from 2016 and 2017 which have same `code`

I have a simple select like

```
SELECT *
FROM products P
INNER JOIN seasons S ON S.id = P.id_season
WHERE S.active = 1
AND S.season_name IN ( YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1  )
```

but don't know how to refine it, to match the codes on products from different seasons.

Comment: what result is produce using this query?

Comment: Have you tried group by code?? or for a specific code, you can put where clause

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code..

```
;WITH cte_1
AS
(SELECT *,COUNT(p.code) OVER(partition by p.code Order by  p.code) cnt
 FROM products P
   INNER JOIN seasons S ON S.id = P.id_season
WHERE S.active = 1
AND S.season_name IN ( YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1  )) -- or simply put IN ('2016','2017')
SELECT *
FROM cte_1
WHERE cnt>1
```

or you can use a subquery format as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *,COUNT(p.code) OVER(partition by p.code Order by  p.code) cnt
 FROM products P
   INNER JOIN seasons S ON S.id = P.id_season
WHERE S.active = 1
AND S.season_name IN ( YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1  )) t
WHERE  t.nt>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner query as follows:

```
 SELECT * FROM products
 where id_season in (Select id from seasons where
 season_name IN ( YEAR(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1  ));
```